# Does getMinBufferSize always return the same value for AudioTrack and AudioRecord?

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack, audiorecord, android-native-library

In Android, when using the classes [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack), and [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord), you can find the minimum buffer size (for a given sample rate, channel config, and audio format) for the user's device with the static methods:

```
AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig, int audioFormat)
```

and

```
AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig, int audioFormat)
```

I'd like to know if the buffer size is guaranteed to be the same for each of these classes independently... as long as it is running on the same device and uses the same config/arguments?

I've tested two devices and they *seem* to be the same.  But is there some known fact/s that guarantee it?

The reason I'm asking is that I have an app that uses both classes and I'd like to establish a safe, shared config for recording and playback.

Comment: Did you get any answer to this? I am in the very same situation as you.

Comment: No I never got an answer. I think I just took the higher of the two results just in case they were ever different.

Comment: I suppose you could look at the source code to see if they both call the same underlying api... I never tried that.

Comment: I just computed it twice.